# jquery sortable connected lists and selectable together?

Tags: jquery

I have 2 lists and I am using the sortable feature - works great.  But I also need to be able to select multiple items and drag those to the connected list as well.  I have 100's of items in a given list and dragging 1 at a time is a bit painful.

Has anyone achieved this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked out the [Multi-Select, Drag & Drop](http://plugins.scbfolio.com/jquery_drag_drop_select/) jQuery plugin? I'm not sure if it handles the sortable feature but the code is quite simple and should be a good start for you.

Comment: looks like just what I need, I could add in sorting afterwards - thanks!